# What's the best way to get access to the Windows Installation process?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, installation

The question sounds a bit weird and I'll try to clarify it. I need to document installing Windows onto a PC and get photos of it for an assignment I'm doing. It can be any edition of Windows but I'd prefer XP up. I have a desktop PC that I've been toying around with that has XP installed on it but do not have the Windows XP disc anymore. I'm not 100% sure I actually had an installation disc for Windows XP in the first place. I would appreciate any solutions or help. I'm sorry if this question isn't worded well or considered suitable. I have a lot of difficulty writing decent questions that meet standards here but I'm getting quite desperate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think your question is really 'on topic' for here but I understand the feels of assignment stress so here you go: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Windows-XP

Comment: Thanks for the link but one of the problems I have is not having the CD unfortunately.

Comment: Here is a link to the Microsoft ISO (image of a cd, you can put it on a usb stick and install it from there) - http://getintopc.com/softwares/operating-systems/windows-xp-sp3/ - and here's a guide on how to put it on a usb stick - http://getintopc.com/tutorials/how-to-install-windows-xp-with-usb-drive/ - please let me know if you have more questions or if this answers it for you (and mark the question answered if so)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm just going through the tutorial now.

Comment: I just cancelled the process of making the USB bootable out of fear it would wipe my computer. When I press 'start' on the Rufus software and when the process of making it bootable is ended does it automatically boot the Windows XP installation? I was doing the process of creating the bootable USB on a laptop I use for work. If possible I would like to unplug the USB and then plug it into the older desktop I have.

Comment: You're safe, it will not automatically restart once the drive is bootable. You can finish that, move the usb to the other computer, and then run it from there on power up. If for some reason your computer does restart, you can always simply remove the drive and not press to continue and press restart and you'll be good as new. Remember to upvote answers you think are helpful and mark them as an answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

Almost all modern versions of windows should have a trial version- I'd grab one of those and install it on a VM. I'd suggest virtualbox since it has a handy video capture feature (so you can record the entire process *once* then screenshot the tasty bits), and there's no need for physical media. It won't risk your main system in any way, and you can blow away the install you just did once your done.

XP is quite EOL and unless you already have a copy/licence, but windows 7/8/8.1 trials are trivial to [download from microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-8-1-enterprise)